# WordPress publishing failed; javascript shows errors 'Access to fetch ... has been blocked by CORS policy'

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have uploaded WordPress manually on freewebhostingarea.com using my own domain. When I create a new page in Wordpress, I get some errors in javascript console (attached image1) but it lets me add/edit content. When I try to publish the page, I get the error 'Updating failed' and javascript console gives additional errors (attached image2) as below:

"Access to fetch at 'http://e.freewebhostingarea.com/not-found.html' (redirected from 'http://www.shia-match.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/16/autosaves?_locale=user') from origin 'http://www.shia-match.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

What could I be doing wrong?

[Errors when creating a new WordPress page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFttE.png),
[Errors when trying to publish page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmYoh.png)

Comment: If you're planning on using your site for any kind of commercial purpose, you should not be hosting on a free server.  Free servers are typically ad supported, which is unprofessional and makes your site look untrustworthy.  Additionally functionality is typically limited and the server is almost always a shared environment; so you're not guaranteed any resources.

Comment: I agree, @JustinR. I'm using a free host while developing my site and plan to move to a paid host when the site is ready. I believe it is going to take me a month or two to make it ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just copied your wordpress files and db from one location to another?  If so, you will need to change settings in your wordpress config as well as in your database to make sure the new location is not referring to the old location's database or files.

Comment: No @mediaguru, it is a new site, a new wordpress upload and a new database. Just to be sure, I deleted all the files, folders and database and uploaded wordpress manually again, created a new database and ran wordpress installation, being careful not to use any old references. Another wordpress site that I created a few days ago in the exact same way but is hosted on another host is working fine. I'm not sure if a host has anything to do with this error but I think that my host is doing this.

Comment: Perhaps some part of your site is trying to fetch files or data from a different URL, causing your CORS issue then.  

If you are simply using the free site to develop, I would suggest not doing that and learning how to develop on your local system.

Comment: That was an issue with the host. I hosted my website with infinityfree.com and it is now running smooth.

Answer (score 2):

Just had this same problem, the cross origin (CORS) policy blocking fetching by the https:// version of a site from the https://www version.

mediaguru’s answer alerted me to check the wp-config file. I found that I had added these lines, and so removed them:

define('WP_HOME', 'https://www.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.example.com');

I then rechecked WP’s Settings > General > WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL). Prior to my edit of the wp-config file, they had displayed the www URL, but greyed out and non-editable. Now they had both reverted to the *non* www version of the URL (and were editable).

On my (Dreamhost) server, the canonical URL is set to www. So I changed the Settings > General URLs to www and… bingo. Solved.

Comment: worked with `Settings > General > WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL).` setting it to whatever cors was asking for